# What to do with a question that has been answered on another SE site

Tags: support, migration, duplicate-questions

Today I have seen [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907846/python-novice-needs-style-advice), where a user commented that it may fit better in CodeReview.SE. The author [posted it again](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19683/python-novice-tictac-toe-gui-code-review) voluntarily on this site and it was successfully answered.

As I've read on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137861/is-it-ok-to-copy-code-from-an-answer-on-one-se-site-to-an-answer-on-another-se-s), if the author of the answer copies the same answer and the OP accepts it again on SO, there won't be any problem. However, that is not the case and it is very likely that this question remains unanswered since the OP has already solved his problem. What is the correct way to handle these posts?

Comment: I think that for SO that can safely be closed as "too localized".

Comment: @Bart Yes, it looks like this question has been useful to close it. However, does this apply in all cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In most situations, a question does not need to be on two sites at once. If a question belongs to the scope of a different site (especially if this is being pointed out in the comments), it is reasonable to assume that it is off topic on the site it was originally asked, and therefore should be closed as such.

The answer you have linked to provides a legal perspective on attribution, but doesn't address at all whether or not duplicating content within the network is a good thing. In this case at least, I don't think there would be any value in the answer being reposted on SO and accepted.

Comment: Yes, I've flagged with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047521/how-would-i-combine-command-and-composite-to-simulate-a-time-delay) which [was answered on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188198/how-would-i-combine-command-and-composite-to-simulate-a-time-delay) and it has been closed. Thanks for your answer.