# Question answered by a NON-SE site - what to do?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

This should be considered the **general case** to:

[What to do with a question that has been answered on another SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173365/what-to-do-with-a-question-that-has-been-answered-on-another-se-site)

Upon encountering a good question in SE/SO that has been answered from a non-SE/SO source, e.g. word of mouth, textbook, social media, un-related forum. Shall I:

1. Try to summarize the answer
2. Paste a link (if possible)
3. Both above?
4. Other?

Comment: --> 3) Both above

Comment: 5.) Disregard the sources, and write a better, original answer.

Comment: Just to add: if it's a trivial question and you found the answer at spot #1 when Googling the question title, it's possible that the question should not exist in the first place. (But that's not the case you describe.)

Comment: Cheers, there have been several instances where I have seen the opportunity to do the "both" approach. Will go back and search for them again now :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

3) Both.

If you found an off-site resource that answers a question, summarize the answer so people don't have to leave the site in order for it to be useful.

But also attribute the answer (your summary) to the source - a good way to do that is link to it.

---

Another option is to write your own, original, in depth answer. (as [JoshC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/232567/joshc) [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208703/question-answered-by-a-non-se-site-what-to-do#comment666184_208703)).

Comment: Ah attribute the source, right'o cheers!